# Getting list of tests from JUnit command line

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

My problem, in short, is that I want to run some JUnit tests from a command line and I would like to be able to see:

- A list of all tests (whether they ran or not).
- A list of all  tests which passed.
- A list of all tests which failed

The reason for the first bullet, is because I believe if one test calls System.exit, the others won't run, I still want to know about these tests, even if they didn't run.

Lets say I have this test class:

```
    import junit.framework.TestCase;
    public class ALoadOfTests extends TestCase {

    public void testFoo() {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 10;
        int result = a + b;
        assertEquals(15, result);
    }

    public void testBar() {
        fail();
    }

    public void testBaz() {
        fail();
    }       
}
```

If I run this using the commands:

```
javac -cp ".;C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test\junit-4.11.jar;C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" ALoadOfTests.java
java -cp ".;C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test\junit-4.11.jar;C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" junit.textui.TestRunner ALoadOfTsts
```

The output is:

```
.F.F.
Time: 0.002
There were 2 failures:
1) testBar(ALoadOfTests)junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
        at ALoadOfTests.testBar(ALoadOfTests.java:12)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2) testBaz(ALoadOfTests)junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
        at ALoadOfTests.testBaz(ALoadOfTests.java:16)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 3,  Failures: 2,  Errors: 0
```

The problem here is that the output doesn't tell me the name of testFoo which exists and passed.
Furthermore, if I change one of them to use System.exit, then we don't get much output at all, we just get:

```
.F.F.
```

Ideally, to be able to get all the information I need, if I could print out a list of test names first, before any tests are ran (and any chance of System.exit) then I can see which passed and which failed (or didn't run).

If I could get output that just looks similar to:

```
Tests:
testFoo
TestBar
TestBaz
Results:
TestFoo(passed)
TestBar(failed:reason)
```

Then I could safely assume:

```
TestFoo passed
TestBar failed
TestBaz never ran, probably because some test called system.exit.
```

Is this possible using a custom runner? If it is, any hints on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Unfortunately I have no control over the code, it should be assumed that it may contain System.exit, possibly, in every method. I also have little control over the tests, so printing out the test names in the setup method isn't ideal.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Changing JUnit output**

As described in this [blog](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/12/12/how-to-add-listner-in-junit-testcases/)  you can write your own test listener and print out your own messages for when tests pass or fail.

```
public class ExecutionListener extends RunListener
{
... //feel free to override other methods too

/**
 *  Called when an atomic test has finished, whether the test succeeds or fails.
 * */
public void testFinished(Description description) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println("Finished execution of test case : "+ description.getMethodName());
}

/**
 *  Called when an atomic test fails.
 * */
public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println("Execution of test case failed : "+ failure.getMessage());
}

/**
 *  Called when a test will not be run, generally because a test method is annotated with Ignore.
 * */
public void testIgnored(Description description) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println("Execution of test case ignored : "+ description.getMethodName());
}
```

}

Then write your own class with a main to run Junit (instead of running the junit.jar)

```
public class ExecuteWithRunListener
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore();
        //Adding listener here
        runner.addListener(new ExecutionListener());
        runner.run(TestFeatureOne.class, TestFeatureTwo.class);
    }
}
```

**How to prevent calls from System.exit from actually exiting**

Your tests can use their own `SecurityManager` to prevent calls to `System.exit` from doing anything.  The code below will make any calls to System.exit() throw a special Exception which we can catch in our tests to make sure we called exit and to also capture what the exit code was:

```
public static final SecurityManager NON_EXITABLE_MANAGER = new SecurityManager(){

    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
        //allow everything
    }
    /**
     * Throws a {@link TriedToExitException} instead of exiting.
     * <p/>
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void checkExit(int status) {
        throw new TriedToExitException(status);
    }

};

public static final class TriedToExitException extends SecurityException{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int exitCode;

    public TriedToExitException(int exitCode){
        this.exitCode=exitCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return String.format("tried to System.exit(%d)",exitCode);
    }

    public int getExitCode() {
        return exitCode;
    }

}
```

Then in your unit tests you replace the SecurityManager with our version that stops calls to exit (and save the old SecurityManager so we can restore it after the test)

```
private SecurityManager previousManager=null;


@Before
protected void replaceManager() throws Throwable {
    previousManager = System.getSecurityManager();
    System.setSecurityManager(NON_EXITABLE_MANAGER);
}

@After
protected void restoreManager() {
    System.setSecurityManager(previousManager);
}

 @Test
    public void testCallToExit() throws IOException{

         try{
           //something that calls System.exit
            fail("should call exit");
         }catch(TriedToExitException e){
             //make sure we get correct exit code
             assertEquals(-1, e.getExitCode());

         }
    }
```