# Test console output using JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to test console output of another program using JUnit. I followed the answers given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119385/junit-test-for-system-out-println)

Here is my JUnit class

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import org.junit.*;

public class MainTest {
        private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        @Before
        public void setup() {
                System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
                System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
        }

        @Test
        public void test01_initTest() {
                String[] arguments = {"a", "b"};
                Main.main(arguments);
                String expected = "hello";
                assertTrue(expected == outContent.toString());
        }

        @After
        public void cleanUpStreams() {
            System.setOut(null);
            System.setErr(null);
        }
}
```

When I run this program in eclipse, neither do I see the console output and the test run doesn't end. However if I printout on console directly from test01_initTest(), the test passes. To check if Main.main() is printing out I also tried the below code and I do see the console output in this case

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.*;

public class MainTest {
        @Test
        public void test01_initTest() {
                String[] arguments = {"a", "b"};
                Main.main(arguments);
        }
}
```

I tired a lot of things but I'm unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Why are you using assertTrue? Use AssertEquals(expected, outContent.toString()). `==` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Hi Falmarri, I tried that too but the result is same. I do not see any output on the console and the test run doesn't end

Comment: We would have to see the code of `Main`.  You don't call System.exit() in Main do you?

Comment: Wait, why are you expecting console output? You're setting your stdout and stderr to other streams.

Comment: Hey dkatzel, Yes I use System.exit() in my program. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit can not complete normally if the code you are testing calls `System.exit()`.

If that main thread terminates, JUnit will just hang.

A workaround is to use a `SecurityManager` to prevent calls to `System.exit()`

In this other StackOverflow answer, I describe how to write such a SecurityManager:

[Getting list of tests from JUnit command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038351/getting-list-of-tests-from-junit-command-line)

(code copied here just in case).

This SecurityManager will throw a custom `TriedToExitException` when `System.exit()` is called and preserves the exit code so you can catch the exception and test that the correct exit code was used.

```
/**
 * A special implementation of {@link SecurityManager}
 * that will throw a {@link TriedToExitException}
 * if {@link System#exit(int)} is called.
 * This is useful for testing main methods
 * without shutting
 * down the jvm running junit.
 * Tests can catch {@link TriedToExitException}
 * to figure out what exit code was set.
 */
public static final SecurityManager NON_EXITABLE_MANAGER = new SecurityManager(){

    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
        //allow everything
    }
    /**
     * Throws a {@link TriedToExitException} instead of exiting.
     * <p/>
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void checkExit(int status) {
        throw new TriedToExitException(status);
    }

};

public static final class TriedToExitException extends SecurityException{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int exitCode;

    public TriedToExitException(int exitCode){
        this.exitCode=exitCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return String.format("tried to System.exit(%d)",exitCode);
    }

    public int getExitCode() {
        return exitCode;
    }
```

Then in your unit tests you replace the SecurityManager with our version that stops calls to exit (and save the old SecurityManager so we can restore it after the test)

```
private SecurityManager previousManager=null;


@Before
protected void replaceManager() throws Throwable {
    previousManager = System.getSecurityManager();
    System.setSecurityManager(NON_EXITABLE_MANAGER);
}

@After
protected void restoreManager() {
    System.setSecurityManager(previousManager);
}

 @Test
public void testCallToExit() throws IOException{

     try{
       //something that calls System.exit
        fail("should call exit");
     }catch(TriedToExitException e){
         //make sure we get correct exit code
         assertEquals(-1, e.getExitCode());

     }
}
```